# Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds (chapter integration, ex. 3, p. 90)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

- Let $[0,1]^{2}=[0,1] \times[0,1] .$ Let $f:[0,1]^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by setting $f(x, y)=0$ if $y \neq x,$ and $f(x, y)=1$ if $y=x .$ Show that $f$ is integrable over $[0,1]^{2}.$

**I will use the Theorem 10.3** (The Riemann condition). Let $Q$ be a rectangle; let $f: Q \rightarrow \boldsymbol{R}$ be a bounded function. Then

$$\int_{Q} f \leq \overline{\int_{Q}} f$$

equality holds iff given $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a corresponding partition $P$ of $Q$ for which

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon$$

I think, we choose partition $\dfrac {1} {k}\times \dfrac {1} {k} $

**How can I prove, may you help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_n = \{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}, \ldots, 1\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$. This induces a partition $P^{\prime}_n$ on the rectangle $[0,1]^2$. 
[image]

Clearly, from the picture above, $$U(f,P^{\prime}_n) = \frac{3n-2}{n^2} \\ L(f,P^{\prime}_n) = 0.$$

Given any $\epsilon> 0$, there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N , \frac{3n-2}{n^2} < \epsilon $. This implies that, given any $\epsilon> 0$, there is a partition $P^{\prime}_N$ such that $$U(f,P^{\prime}_N) - L(f,P^{\prime}_N) < \epsilon.$$

Thus, $f$ is integrable.

We can also use the fact that a function $g$ is integrable iff it is bounded and the set of discontinuities of $g$ is of measure zero. The set of discontinuities of $f$ here is $\{ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2 | x=y \}$, which is a set of measure zero. Thus, it follows directly that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: How did you find  $U(f,P^{\prime}_n) = \frac{3n-2}{n^2} ,L(f,P^{\prime}_n) = 0$ may you explain, please?

Comment: Looking at the partition of $[0,1]^2$, we see that in the diagonal subrectangles ($n$ of them) and the off-diagonal subrectangles ($2n-2$ of them)the supremum is $1$ and the infimum is $0$. Elsewhere, supremum and infimum both are zero.

Comment: I have added a picture in the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer and commend